# How can I move my files from my directory to another directory without getting an exception

Tags: c#

It keeps throwing an exception:

> Ant JSON Serializer Failed: The process cannot access the file because
>   it is being used by another process.

I know there are a lot of posts out there to fix that exception but it won't apply to my code. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
static string antJsonSerializer(){
    #region  KDI SALES
    string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\");

    // Put all file names in root directory into array.
    string sourceDirectory = @"C:\xml";
    string destinationDirectory = @"C:\xml\Archive";

    // Check if directories are existing
    bool xmlRoot = System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory);
    if (!xmlRoot) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDirectory);

    bool xmlArchive = System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory);
    if (!xmlArchive) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDirectory);

    AntHelpers drone = new AntHelpers();
    foreach (string name in allfiles)
    {                
        try
        {
            drone.xmltosql(@name.Trim());
            Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory); //Archive
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Main Process Catch ERR: " + e.Message);
            //ErrLogtoDB(string TRNTYPE, string extserial, string texttowrite, string logfilename)
            AntHelpers.ErrLogtoDB("SALES", "", "Ant JSON Serializer Failed: " + e.Message, 
                "LeafCutterLogFile_JSONSerializer_" + (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString() + (DateTime.Now.Month).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Hour).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ".html");               
        }                
        //drone.ExtractSQLSendAntHill(); //For testing: OFF 
    #endregion            
    }

    return " !!!! Work Complete !!!! ";
}
```

Comment: what does the method `drone.xmltosql()` do? are you sure that it closes the reader/writer when done?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is trying to move the entire directory - try `File.Move` instead:

```
string newPath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(name));
File.Move(name, newPath);
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the title. Yes, I'm trying to move all files to another directory but, I'm getting the exception.

Comment: If you still get the exception, the file is probably still in use by `drone.xmltosql()` (or something else still has it open).

Comment: Anyway to terminate or end that process in C# you can suggest?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay I don't know what that method does, if it's your code just make sure you `Dispose` the `FileStream` or find other ways to release the resources used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
// Ensure that the target does not exist. 
if (File.Exists(destinationPath))   
    File.Delete(destinationPath);

// Move the file.
File.Move(sourcePath, destinationPath);
```

Refer [File.Move Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for more details.

Comment: I have tested this code on my machine and it's working fine. No idea about what's going wrong on your side. Have you gone through given link. There are some example codes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to both of you @C.Evenhuis & @manoj_rp. I fixed my File.Move(); It is now File.Move(@name, "ArchivedlogName.txt"); I'll up-vote both.